# I find partial methods very useful, but there are no partial properties. Is there a good reason they were not included? What are my alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net

UPDATE:
Please note that I know I cannot do this...this is what I was really hoping could work. Maybe there is some other way that would separate responsibility, no? So what I am looking for is...

Entity Framework forces multiple responsibilities into the class (regular logic, basic annotations, and CRUD interface ability). I just want to take what would normally all be in one class...and separate the persistent ability of the class via Entity Framework and the regular logic.

---

MY THOUGHT PROCESS: Recently I have been getting into Entity Framework, but don't like the idea that some of the Entity classes are doing somewhat too much. Logic, interfacing with data access, and Entity Framework Annotations. To fix this, I wanted to make my Entity class file partial, and implement the data access functionality away from the other aspects of the class. This works well and is very clean!

While I was doing that, I figured it would be greatly beneficial to make my properties partial, and have the implementation away from the EF Property Annotations!! This would clear up the files and allow single responsibility. However, this is not allowed! Bummer.

The partial properties would be implemented just like partial methods. The definition in one partial property, and the implementation in the other partial property...just like the photos suggest (or the comments) in the link at the top, and the code below.

```
public partial class Agency : PropertyValidator, IAgency
{
    private string _name;

    public partial string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            // PropertyValidator stuff
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                AddErrorToProperty("Agency name must contain a reasonable alphanumeric value.");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))   
                AddErrorToProperty("Agency name cannot contain all spaces.");

            SetPropertyIfValid(ref _name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is the other partial class that handles all abstract database items...

```
public partial class Agency : IPersitentEntity, IAgency
{       
    [Key]    // NOTE these Annotations are because of Entity Framework...nice separation! 
    public int ID { get; set; } // From IPersitentEntity

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
    public partial string Name { get; set; } // IAgency NOTE this is not valid, but the 
                                             // separation is amazing!

    // From IPersitentEntity provide CRUD support
    public void Create() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Retrieve(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Update(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Delete(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Right now, I have to combine the Annotations and Logic together. It is kind  of weird because I already separated out the abstract database items...except the EF Annotations!

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask for support.  SO is here to help with programming questions.

Comment: I thought this would be....PLEASE don't down vote me any more

Comment: You can get back any lost reputation by deleting the question. It's likely to be closed or removed soon anyway.

Comment: I think this does validate for Programming, no? Maybe there is a why I don't know to do what I want? I just thought since MS offers a venue to  add features I would throw this out there.

Comment: SO is more for questions about actual code. This is a question that will start discussions, and is therefore not a good fit for SO. Besides there is no way to offer assistance since you're talking about a feature you would like to see in c# - not one that already exists.

Comment: SO is for asking questions about code that you've written, not trying to convince people about your cause.  There isn't an answer to this, so it doesn't fit the Q and A format.

Comment: IS there a community under the stackoverflow group that is best for this question? Something more discussion oriented?

Comment: Not really - the StackExchange platform is a Q&A platform. I think you'd be better off looking at forums.

Comment: This isn't a bad question. I'm pretty sure you can rephrase it to fit SO, something like: *"I find partial methods very useful, but there are no partial properties. Is there a good reason they were not included? **What are my alternatives?**"*. There's a real programming problem hidden under your suggestion. (you really need to change the content a little, not just the title  `:)` )

Comment: Yeah...hence my question on this...and my looking for answers. Discussions start from questions, too, and I have written this code trying to fix a problem that I had. Maybe this is an XY problem?

Hence me asking if there was another way of doing what I wanted in the comments

Comment: If you primarily wanted an answer to a question, you wouldn't have lead with the link to the site you're asking people to vote on.  If you want an answer to your problem, I'd delete this question, rewrite the text to remove references to your desired feature and repost. Make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to read up on `persistence ignorance` and why making each of your entities inherit from `IPersitentEntity` is a "bad thing".

Comment: @ta.speot.is ... please enlighten me on this. I have never heard of that term before, and I am looking at it right now. The idea behind that was simple, because C# allows partial classes...I would have one partial class that dealt specifically with the the logic, and another with database-like items.

I could see that I might delete `IPersitentEntity`... that is just in there now until I see it is wrong...have not looked at it much yet

Comment: I am currently retrofitting my project I made before...slowly working new things in...so the `IPersitentEntity` might go...thought it would be good to consolidate a subset of the CRUD operations and the ID. Seems to look good now...but I am nowhere near close to finished

Comment: OK...I found a good reference to `persistence ignorance` and understand it on a higher level....apparently not low enough as @ta.speot.is has suggested. Why is that?

Comment: Regarding the basics of your request: Please consider that everyone loves to see short code blocks - short classes, methods, and properties. But having things "partial" is not really making them short, it feigns overview and leads to classes having a lot of responsibilities.

Comment: @oddparity Thanks for your comment...I do agree with you that it can. Maybe there is even a better way of doing this? Like I have stated several times in the comments. Entity Framework *forces* multiple responsibilities into the class (regular logic, basic annotations, and CRUD interface ability). I just want to take what would normally all be in one class...and separate the persistent ability of the class via Entity Framework and the regular logic.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Sorry, I am not the right guy answering that. I am using NHibernate in my project right now (and would rather switch to Ibatis if in need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `partial` is mainly for code generation, I have found it useful to separate out different responsibilities in the class that I have deemed not recommended to change my code base to facilitate that small level of separation on my own person projects. I have never seen that done in the field...again besides code generation.

I don't know if this is a personal project, but if it was, I would just use the partial like you have to separate out the persistent items. I have looked at websites that separate out this further by creating another level between the database code and the business logic. Implementing that can be a burdensome if you never did it before, and adds a good amount of classes to your project.

If this is a personal project, that might not be worth it, and if you want to "separate" out the different responsibilities, then partial classes your way does seem to work. If you need to change the way you access data, then you change that partial class only, no touching of the regular business logic.

[EDIT] But you are out of look with the separation of the Annotations on the properties most likely, but I wonder...

If you declared the properties in the persistent partial class, but called getter and setter private methods in the regular business logic partial class!?!? This way the logic is in that one partial class, and the Annotations will be in the other partial class where you want them

Comment: That sounds genius with the Annotations! Not sure I will like how they are separated...but that does sound like it might work!!!

Answer (score 8):

Part of the reason that there are no `partial` properties is that they don't fit into the basic design philosophy of `partial` members.  The goal is to simply define a stub that a code generator could plug extra logic into if needed.  If the code generated didn't fill in the method then all calls to the `partial` stub would be removed from the final program.

To meet this goal a `partial` method has some pretty limiting restrictions including that it must return `void`.  This makes it very easy to compile away because there is no value that can remain if it is removed

```
SomePartialMethod();
```

Properties on the other hand can never be `void`, they must be some concrete type.  Hence the user can always write the following

```
string x = SomePartialProperty;
```

This is impossible for the compiler to completely erase.  This expression must assign some value to `x` else the program simply can't compile.  To make this work the compiler would likely have to pick an appropriate default value for `x`.  It certainly could do this, (say `default(T)` but I imagine this factored into the decision to not have this feature.

Comment: OK...thanks for this info! But do you see a work around to the way I wanted? To seperate all persistent logic from the entity logic?

I am sure that the compiler could do * * something * * in later versions that might allow for something like what I wanted to do, right? or no...never mind the partial property stuff...could some other thing be used?

Comment: That's a good point, so I guess my suggested title isn't good. But I think this isn't what troubles the OP: He would like to have the property's implementation on one file, and attributes on another - similar to partial classes. He does not need a property that might not be implemented.

Comment: So I guess I have two things now...the question above, and the following.

If this could be done, and it was not bad programming practice, I think it would be good to suggest this to Microsoft Connect. As I do think this does facilitate single responsibility into something that  forces multiple responsibility (Entity Framework).

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski unfortunately I don't really see a way.  My instinct in this scenario would be to define a wrapper type around `Agency` that implemented the custom property logic I wanted.

Comment: @Christopher - not really. It is still the same class, so the class still has multiple responsibilities. `partial` is mainly used for generated code, not for architecture.

Comment: Yes...that is why I said that EF forces multiple responsibilities. This would kind of be a why that kind of separates that. Yes, it all gets compiled into one class. I understand that.

Comment: I see something like this link is what you are talking about ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#C.23_Implementation_of_Adapter_Pattern