# I was told this is bad programming practice, don't know why | Persistent Ignorance implemented wrong?

Tags: c#, abstraction, persistent

I had posted the following code on another question of mine recently. Please forgive the partial properties, that is something I `Wanted` to do, but could not...

```
public partial class Agency : PropertyValidator, IAgency
{
    private string _name;

    public partial string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            // PropertyValidator stuff
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                AddErrorToProperty("Agency name must contain a reasonable alphanumeric value.");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))   
                AddErrorToProperty("Agency name cannot contain all spaces.");

            SetPropertyIfValid(ref _name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Agency : IPersitentEntity, IAgency
{       
    [Key]    // NOTE these Annotations are because of Entity Framework...nice separation! 
    public int ID { get; set; } // From IPersitentEntity

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
    public partial string Name { get; set; } // IAgency NOTE this is not valid, but the 
                                             // separation is amazing!

    // From IPersitentEntity provide CRUD support
    public void Create() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Retrieve(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Update(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Delete(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

...in it, I had one comment without a reply on stackoverflow that said...

`You might want to read up on persistence ignorance and why making each of your entities inherit from IPersitentEntity is a "bad thing".`

---

I never heard of `Persistence Ignorance` before, and had to look it up. Turns out I knew what the concept was, not the term. However, I am a little confused as to why what I am doing IS bad.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your class now has multiple axis of change. It can change if your business model changes, and also change due to changes at your database layer. This breaks the "Single Responsibility Principle"

Look up the SOLID principles, Here is a podcast with Robert Martin and Scott Hanselmen that discribes them

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast145SOLIDPrinciplesWithUncleBobRobertCMartin.aspx

Comment: OK...for more information to * * WHY * * I did this format for the code, check out this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372233/i-find-partial-methods-very-useful-but-there-are-no-partial-properties-is-ther

Comment: Entity Framework forces multiple responsibilities into the class (regular logic, basic annotations, and CRUD interface ability). I just want to take what would normally all be in one class...and separate the persistent ability of the class via Entity Framework and the regular logic.

Comment: I wanted the IPersistentEntity interface because all my main entities would have DB interface functionality...they would have ID's and CRUD support. Also, in that question, I also wanted to separate Entity Framework's Annotations from the *regular* class logic...as that was DB-like additions

Comment: Entity Framework (i think 4 and above?) support POCO classes and the dbContext object represents a repository + unit of work pattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx This link shows you how to do dataaccess using EF with POCO classes http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/561584/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-using

Comment: I am listening to the podcast right now....and I think my S and O in SOLID is there.

I am looking to emulate single responsibility as much as possible, given that EF enforces multiple responsibility (basic logic, annotations for ORM, and CRUD support)

I think it also implements the O (Open-close principle). I have separated what can change a lot (the CRUD abilities possible) from what is basically going to stay the same (the regular logic of the entity).

So far everything SEEMS to follow SOLID right now - at least SO

Comment: Look at the links in the comment above yours, EF does support POCO classes, you can seperate out the CRUD operations by implementing a Repository like pattern

Comment: The class as a whole doesnt follow Either S or O ! :) It has two responsibilities (Business logic and Data access logic) and is not open for extension. How would you implement a different persistance mechanism for example? you would have to rewrite the CRUD operations within the class